# Falta de Assembly Reference C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho um erro de falta de uso do `Directive` ou um `Assembly Reference` apontado para`KeyCod`e `Modifiers`

Alguém sabe dizer qual seria e como posso carrega-lo ?

```
    private void lblAutoCod_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.C && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("You pressed ctrl + c");
        }
    }
```

A finalidade é fazer quem em um click em cima de uma `label` o texto seja copiado.

Segue: 
[image: Erro na prática]

Answer (score 5):

Você está confundindo o evento. O correto é [`KeyEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx). Não [`MouseEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx). Seu código não faz sentido.

Se o objetivo é testar qual botão do *mouse* foi pressionado, mude o evento para:

```
private void lblAutoCod_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Botão direito do mouse pressionado.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Exato! Eu ia mesmo dizer isso. Qual o sentido de tentar capturar uma tecla (do teclado) num evento disparado quando ocorre um clique do mouse?

Comment: Sei... faz sentido agora. Então talvez meu raciocinio não está chegando onde eu quero chegar de verdade. Talvez uma pergunta totalmente diferente me ajudasse. Ex: Num Evento `Mouse_Click` em cima de uma Label, o `texto` dessa Label seja copiado (como se eu tivesse dado um **CTRL+C** no `texto` da label) ..

Comment: Sim, melhor tentar outra pergunta.